# Scripting - Pie Menus

Tags: pie-menu

How do I write a script that would goto my custom workspace and initiate the mode set.

I want it so when I swipe to Modelling in my pie menu it chooses my "Modelling" workspace and goes to object mode, not edit mode.

I have pie menus installed, will I write it in script from then run it from pie.

here are some of the code snippets I've managed to collect.

wm.context_set_id
Context Attribute: window.workspace  Value: Modeling
object.mode_set

wm.context_set_id
Context Attribute: window.workspace Value: Sculpting
sculpt.mode_set

Answer (score 0):

bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0].workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['Modeling']
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

Comment: it appears you can't stop it from always going into edit mode, why blender, WHY!

Comment: well, the whole point of having a modeling workspace is to model, ie, edit, so that's why.  You can delete it and add your own workspace that you call it Modeling.  If you derive that workspace from Layout it can be set up any way you want.

Comment: It's cool, I just model and sculpt with-in the workspace now, don't need to worry about what I was trying to do above. Was cool that workspaces change the desired tabs and buttons to ones preference. meh!